# neither mobile broadband nor wireless connects on ubuntu whereas it does in windows 7 running parallely

Tags: wireless, mobile-broadband

i am using ubuntu 12.04 on my dell inspiron n5010. I read almost all the posts available but couldn't get my internet connection established. I have an MTS Mblaze usb net connect. i added the device using the network options giving all my details(place, time and all). now when i run it, it doesn't work. firstly a message appears saying connection established and then a message of network disabled follows it immediately.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then **edit** your question adding the information.